# datepicker-ui click on date display popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I added some events to a datepicker ui calendar (assigned to a div so it's always visible) with an specific title each one. When clicking on any of this special dates I want to show a popup with the title of the event above the day.

```
var Event = function(text, className) {
this.text = text;
this.className = className; };

var events = {};
events[new Date("02/07/2014")] = new Event("Event01", "highlight");

events[new Date("02/26/2014")] = new Event("Event02", "highlight");
events[new Date("02/27/2014")] = new Event("Event02", "highlight");



$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var event = events[date];
        if (event) {
            return [true, event.className, event.text];
        }
        else {
            return [true, '', ''];
        }
    }});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/saisoto/A5mew/

I think it has something to do with onSelect, but I have no idea as to how position the popup above the date.

I may add that I don't want an alert to pop up in the page and make people click on accept (or close) to let them keep interacting with the page

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`onSelect`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect), if the selected date is a special date show an alert (or something else).

> Called when the datepicker is selected. The function receives the
>   selected date as text and the datepicker instance as parameters. this
>   refers to the associated input field.

Code:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var event = events[date];
        if (event) {
            return [true, event.className, event.text];
        } else {
            return [true, '', ''];
        }
    },
    onSelect: function (date) {
        var event = events[new Date(date)];
        if (event) {
            alert(event.text)
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/ajMS6/

Comment: At first I use that, but it looks like there's some kind of error in the page and I don't want the alert to stop the interaction with the page until you close it or you accept it. Thank for the incredible fast response btw.

Comment: @saisoto you are welcome! So you want to show a non modal popup instead and let the calendar select the date and close? Or show the event text in a field near the date picker?

Comment: Something like that, but since my calendar is always showing I wanted to make that div appear above the date clicked (like a dialogue globe). The positioning is what is giving me trouble